# anagram checker not passing all test cases?

Tags: string, anagram

I am doing a online code challenge that asks to write a anagram checker program. So i made the following the program and for some weird reason it's not passing all the test cases. I wrote a main function on my own and tried to test it myself and it seems to work fine.

```
#include<iostream>


using namespace std;

bool anagrams(string str1, string str2);

int main(){
    string str1="abcd";
    string str2="dcba";

    cout<<anagrams(str1,str2)<<endl;
    cin.get();
    return 0;    
}

bool anagrams(string str1, string str2){
    if(str1.length()!=str2.length()) return false;
    for(int i=0;i <str1.length(); i++){
        for(int j=0;j<str2.length();j++){
            if(str1[i]==str2[j]){
                str1[i]='*';
                break;
            }
        }    
    }
    for(int i=0;i<str1.length();i++){
        if(str1[i]!='*') return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so the program wouldn't work with inputs such as

```
abcc
abcd
```

So a quick fix would be marking the character from `str2` with `*` as you iterate through each character in `str1`.

```
#include<iostream>


using namespace std;

bool anagrams(string str1, string str2);

int main(){
    string str1="abcc";
    string str2="dcba";

    cout<<anagrams(str1,str2)<<endl;
    cin.get();
    return 0;    
}

bool anagrams(string str1, string str2){
    if(str1.length()!=str2.length()) return false;
    for(int i=0;i <str1.length(); i++){
        for(int j=0;j<str2.length();j++){
            if(str1[i]==str2[j]){
                str2[j]='*';
                break;
            }
        }    
    }
    for(int i=0;i<str2.length();i++){
        if(str2[i]!='*') return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

There are better algorithms out there for anagram checkers, such as sorting and using a hashable.

Comment: Actually, you only need to mark the target string `str2`, since the source string `str1` is implicitly marked, because no letter is used twice in the outer for. Then check `str2` only for all `*`s.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your code checks if the characters in str1 exist in str2.

For example, if str1="abca" and str2="abcd" they are clearly not anagrams.
However won't it turn str1 into "****" since it will match the last a in str1 to the first a in str2 (twice).

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.datastructures.programs;

public class Anagram {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String s1 = "abcc";
        String s2 = "abcd";

        System.out.println(Anagram.isAnagram(s1, s2));
    }

    private static boolean isAnagram(String s1, String s2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        int[] temp = new int[256];
        boolean isAnagram = true;
        if (s1.length() != s2.length()) {
            return false;
        }

        for (char s : s1.toCharArray()) {
            int index = (int) s;
            temp[index]++;
        }
        for (char s : s2.toCharArray()) {
            int index = (int) s;
            temp[index]--;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
            if (temp[i] != 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post (especially as you appear to be using a different programming language than that used in the question). Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.